# Expect script not working and send status getting skipped

Tags: expect

I have written a script to execute a setup on the server, but while executing send statement is getting skipped and other one getting executed.

Below is my script :

```
enter code here[code written][1]




====================ERROR m getting=============================
Enter the name of the new namespace you want to create [coe_ns] :
Enter the name of the clearinghouse you want to create [coe_ch] : invalid command name "C"
    while executing
"C"
    invoked from within
"expect -re "* Option to execute (Continue/Restart/Quit) [C]: $""
    (file "./TNS_Server_Setup.sh" line 21)
```

I have a doubt that send command before that is not getting executed, also am I passing "ENTER" right way.

Answer (score 0):

expect uses square brackets as the command substitution syntax (in the same way that the shell uses backticks or `$(...)`. So when you write

```
expect -re "* Option to execute (Continue/Restart/Quit) [C]: $"
```

expect sees `[C]` and tries to invoke the command `C`.

Also, that standalone `*` will throw a "quantifier operand invalid" error, because that's a special character for regular expressions. You either need to escape it or remove it from the expression.

Use a different quoting mechanism that inhibits command substitution (like in the shell where you'd use single quotes)

```
expect -re {Option to execute (Continue/Restart/Quit) [C]: $}
```

You did not include your code in the question so we can't see your send command, but to "just hit enter", you would `send "\r"`

---

Update:

If you need to match multiple things, the expect command can do that: give it a list of `pattern action` pairs. Expect will match any of them.

```
expect {
    -re {Option to execute (Continue/Restart/Quit) [C]: $} {
        send "\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re {enter the datatype $} {
        send "array\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "some pattern that denotes we're done"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Glen, I have another query if my expect output is having two line.How can make sure expect matches both the line or my regular expression should take care.
example: enter the datatype 
                from the option:
script:  expect -re "enter the datatype $" should work i believe.